# QSpinBox Arrow Display Issue when using a Stylesheet

Tags: qt, user-interface, qtstylesheets, arrows, qspinbox

Qt 5.12 desktop widgets.

Trying to style a spinbox to match our application's existing colors and the up/down arrow images disappear from the associated buttons.

```
QSpinBox {
  background: #474747;
  color: white;
  border: 2px outset;
  border-top-color: #0E0E0E;
  border-right-color: #525252;
  border-bottom-color: #525252; 
  border-left-color: #0E0E0E;
  font: bold 14px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
QSpinBox::up-arrow {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
QSpinBox::down-arrow {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

Results:

[Resulting spinbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQ9LY.png)

Thanks for reading and in advance for any help.

Tried many different combinations. Also tried being specific and adding in the arrow images however the same results.

```
QSpinBox::up-arrow {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  **image: url(:/images/up_arrow.png);**
}
QSpinBox::down-arrow {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  **image: url(:/images/down_arrow.png);**
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Needed to supply the full stylesheet specification for the button, not just the arrows.

Comment: Can you expand on this?